# Eclipse exported apk crashing

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I need to publish my application, i ran the Eclipse export wizard and exported a signed apk with a self-signed certificate, i also ran the zipalign tool also. The problem is that when installing this package on the device and running it, it crashes directly, although i can run the application directly from eclipse with no problems.
Will that have to do with the proguard configurations or anything else?!

**Update:** the problem is from the proguard configuration file, this is the stack trace of the exception:

```
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.c(Unknown Source)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onPostCreate(Unknown Source)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPostCreate(Instrumentation.java:1115)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1950)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class a is not annotated with @Implementation
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at com.actionbarsherlock.a.a(Unknown Source)
    01-28 17:49:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(14897):    at com.actionbarsherlock.a.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Royi i just posted the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding the -keep to actionbarsherlock and support library classes and interfaces

```
    -keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
    -keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
    -keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
    -keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
```

and by adding the corresponding library jars by using -libraryjars keyword

Comment: I know this is old, but could you add what `-libraryjars` you specified?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes Eclipse just gets bugged out. 
What you can do, which usually helps:

1. Clean your projects
2. Clear your Eclipse workbench settings

How you can exactly do step #2 depends on your OS, but on Mac it is:

1. Go to your workspace
2. Open .metadata (you'll need to be able to see hidden folders for this)
3. Open .plugins
4. Open org.eclipse.e4.workbench
5. Delete workbench.xmi

This will clear your basic workbench settings, which includes things as your views set up.

Try to package your app, before re-doing your workbench settings. 
Usually works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using latest from https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock build fine without any problems on ADT 21.x

Answer (score 1):

This occasionally happens with eclipse. I would suggest you to always try the apk file out on a real device before uploading it to the app store.

The problem gets resolved by cleaning the project and then exporting it again.

Comment: Good advice, thanks.  Pity it's not more reliable as I used to feel confident releasing informal end of sprint demo versions without the mail-apk-to-self-deinstall-old-install-new-and-run-smoke-test step.

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard I used to upload the app to my server. Download it on bluestacks and install it... Luckily I found a better alternative - Geanymotion. You can drag-drop the apk on the emulator. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

when generating signed apk, have to exclude any external jar files and libraries
like below

```
-libraryjars libs

# The official support library.
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

# Library JARs.
-keep class de.greenrobot.dao.** { *; }
-keep interface de.greenrobot.dao.** { *; }
-keep class org.joda.** { *; }
-keep interface org.joda.** { *; }
-keep class com.loopj.android.http.** { *; }
-keep interface com.loopj.android.http.** { *; }

# Library projects. 
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep class com.viewpagerindicator.** { *; }
-keep interface com.viewpagerindicator.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe eclipse runs the zipalign for you, so you dont need to do it yourself. Perhaps try that?

And yes, running from eclipse is in debug, proguard is ignored. The export will be a release build and if proguard is configured in the project.properties it may be taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did the zipalign incorrectly, I don't believe eclipse does this for you.

The correct syntax is

```
zipalign -v 4 /location/to/eclipse/exported/apk /location/of/where/to/output/aligned/apk
```

Comment: Although stack trace would be useful to see as well

Answer (score 0):

Remove proguard optimizations. Do not use zipalign. Test exported package. If it works - fine, recheck zipalign/proguard params, if not - check something else )